# Finding a function definition in MS Access VBA editor

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to edit some code in an existing project with tons of forms, modules, and custom functions. In the relevant event handler I find this:

```
Action = "Some text here I'd rather not share " & Me.UpdatedPrimary
UpdateLog (Action)
```

The UpdateLog() function is not anywhere in this module. How do I find it without manually looking through dozens upon dozens of form objects and modules?

Not very familiar with this code editor. Thank you.

Comment: Right click `UpdateLog` then click *Definition* ?

Comment: Or place the cursor on the name of this function and press SHIFT + F2

Comment: thank you guys. sorry, I'm slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in comments.

Shift + F2  -- the most important keyboard shortcut in the VBA editor. :)

Or via context menu `[right_click] -> Definition` or menu `View -> Definition`.

Note that it doesn't work only for functions, but also for variables etc.

Comment: Since that is the keyboard shortcut for `[right_click] > Definition` and `View > Definition` you might want to mention that in the answer to make it more complete.